# Is there a formal word describing a person or technology consuming most of the resources, which leads to unfairness?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

For example, there are two technologies (X and Y) sharing a resource, but due to some reason, technology X always uses 90% of the resource and leaves only 10% for the other.

And I would do something to prevent the technology X {***a word or words here***} the resource.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: [Verb for refusing to share an item](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/529039/191178)

Comment: @Laurel OK, Thanks! And from the answer, maybe "hog" is more appropriate. But is it formal enough to be written into an academic paper?

Comment: *Monopolize* would be more appropriate for a formal paper. You should add that you need a formal word in your question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Because the context of tech sharing resources, would be computing. Is IT or computing your context?

Comment: @Lambie The context is that a wireless communication technology might monopolize the majority of channel resources, resulting in unfair channel access for WiFi.

Comment: Have these resources been inequitably *allocated*?

Comment: Ah, now you're talking.